# How to put in the ui thread the data from the list of lists Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to put the lists of lists in the ui thread, but i am confised how to do that properly. I am trying to put widgets in the map method and got the error:

```
1. The element type 'List<Text>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'
```

How can I avoid this error if I need to present data from the lists of lists at the same time?

```
List<Common> common = merge(buying, bait, tackle).toList();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          common[index].fishingTackle.map((e) => Text(e.name)),
          common[index].fishBait.map((e) => Text(e.baitName)),
          common[index].time.toString()),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}

 Iterable<Common> merge(List<TimeByuing> buying, List<FishBait> bait,
        List<FishingTackle> tackle) sync* {
      for (int i = 0; i < buying.length; i++) {
        var fishingTackle = tackle.where((v) => v.id == buying[i].id).toList();
        var fishBait = bait.where((v) => v.typeId == buying[i].typeId).toList();
        yield Common(
          id: buying[i].id,
          typeId: buying[i].typeId,
          fishingTackle: fishingTackle,
          fishBait: fishBait,
          time: buying[i].time,
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `Column` widget expects an array of *single* widgets. What you have is effectively a nested array of widgets.

You can use the spread operator on your `map()` to make them work in the column.

Also you need to convert the `iterable` created by `map` to a list by using `toList()` as a `column` can't work with iterables.

```
 ...common[index].fishingTackle.map((e) => Text(e.name)).toList(),
 ...common[index].fishBait.map((e) => Text(e.baitName)).toList(),
```

Your other line `common[index].time.toString()),` will also need to be converted into a `Text` widget as anything `.toString()` will be of type `String` and not `Widget`

You can do this by:

```
Text(common[index].time.toString())),
```